# How to append to a file using PyGithub?

Tags: python, file, github, pygithub

I want to append to an already existing .txt file using PyGithub in Python.
I have tried this code:

```
git = Github(TOKEN)
repo = git.get_repo("Repository")
file = repo.get_contents("Textfile.txt", ref="Ref")

repo.update_file(file.path, "test", "Text I wanna store", file.sha, branch="Ref")
```

but this code deletes the old data and only stores this data i.e. "Text I wanna store" only.

I want to store this data at the end of the previously stored data like
"Previous Data Text I wanna store"

Comment: download the file, append the data, upload the new one...

Comment: I am using this way for now but isn't there a better way to do it. Or any function built in library to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is above is already good, you simply need to take the original Content of the File, and append new one with a + operator or an f-string

Here is an example

```
git = Github(TOKEN)
repo = git.get_repo("Repository")
file = repo.get_contents("Textfile.txt", ref="Ref")
new_data = input("Text you want to add")
update_file(file.path, "NEW COMMIT", f"{file} {new_data}", file.sha,branch="Ref")
```

Comment: I have done so for now but isn't there a better way or a built in function in library to do so

Comment: @VarunSingh No there is not, it probably is the Fastest Way to do it, I read the Docs and this is the simplest and best solution.

Answer (score 1):

**.decoded_content.decode()** Return file content

```
git = Github(TOKEN)
repo = git.get_repo("Repository")
file = repo.get_contents("Textfile.txt", ref="Ref")

repo.update_file(file.path, "test", f"{file.decoded_content.decode()} Text I wanna store ", file.sha, branch="Ref")
```